# How can I change the border color of a combobox in WPF by code (c#)?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, border

Does anyone have an idea how to do that? I need to mark a ComboBox if it wasn't selected.

This method doesn't work:

```
cBoxBasics.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am pretty confident, what you want is some sort of Form or [Data validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview#data-validation)?

Comment: Red border is a default error template. You can [set validation error](https://www.wpftutorial.net/ValidationErrorByCode.html) in the view, where you handle selection changed event. It can be refactored into reusable view-only attached behavior (utilizing selecton events and setting/clearing this error) later, when you start using MVVM.

Comment: The reason it's not as simple as just setting borderbrush is because a combobox has a complicated template. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be surrounding the combobox with a border element and set the border element color in xaml...

```
<Border x:Name="MyBorder" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
    <ComboBox x:Name="cBoxBasics" />
</Border>
```

...or in the code behind

```
MyBorder.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
```

As others have already stated in the comments, there are validation features you could implement instead. Though they might be a bit more complicated to implement and learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you temporarily [create a new resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/how-to-create-and-apply-a-resource?view=vs-2019) for your ComboBox and play around with it, you'll see it contains a border element named `templateRoot` which you need to set the color of. This is made slightly more complex by the fact that the one you need to change is the root child control of a ToggleButton, and it's parent ComboBox also contains its own `templateRoot` named control as well. So to change the color of the ToggleButton's border you need to first find it in the ComboBox, then find it's `templateRoot` Border element and set the color there. You also need to make sure you do this once the control has been templated, otherwise there will be nothing there to change, so do it in the cBoxBasics's Loaded handler:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    this.cBoxBasics.Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        var toggleButton = this.cBoxBasics.Template.FindName("toggleButton", this.cBoxBasics) as ToggleButton;
        var border = toggleButton.Template.FindName("templateRoot", toggleButton) as Border;
        border.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
    };
}
```